# ApacheDS unable to start correctly

Tags: linux, apache, ldap, ubuntu-12.04, apacheds

I recently installed ApacheDS on a Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS,

when I start it via

> sudo /etc/init.d/apacheds-[...]-default start

it gives me this output :

```
chown: invalid user: `@user@:apacheds'
Unknown id: @user@
```

I installed ApacheDS using the binary installer downloaded from the official website. I also used the default settings for everything during the installation.

Is there a work around or a way to make ApacheDS start correctly ?

Thanks